# ListView loosing track of positions

Tags: android, listview, garbage-collection, position

I'm working on a quite heavy ListView app where the listitems are quite heavy. When the user only has a few listitems everything works fine but when the user adds more some problems begin to surface. Interaction with the listitems become harder and sometimes when a item is clicked the user gets the touch effect but no effect. When accesing positions (this is done when using the Contextual Action Bar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB ) the click throws a NullPointerException. I'm pretty sure this is because of the GC killing resources in my app. Are there any general tips on how to avoid this kind of behaviour or possibly some kind of workaround to fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Logcat crash:

```
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at     com.simon.holocountownapp.MainActivity$1.onItemCheckedStateChanged(MainActivity.java:104)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onItemCheckedStateChanged(AbsListView.java:6037)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at android.widget.AbsListView.setItemChecked(AbsListView.java:1013)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2807)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2765)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-07 15:59:39.219: E/AndroidRuntime(8003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 104 (referenced in logcat) calls listView.getChildAt(position) and this most likely returns null which leads to the crash.

The layout is pretty heavy (200+ lines of code) so I'll post it to pastebin.
http://pastebin.se/KTmCA0jc

The adapter:

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CountdownViewHolder holder;
        CountdownItem ci = mTitle.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent,
                false);

        holder = new CountdownViewHolder();
        holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textPrim);
        holder.mSubtitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textSec);
        holder.mOverflow = (ImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        holder.mInfo = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.info);
        holder.expand_layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expand_layout);
        holder.mExpDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_day);
        holder.mExpSec = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_sec);
        holder.mDayProgress = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.day_progress);
        holder.mMonthProgress = (ProgressBar) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.month_progress);
        holder.mYearText = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.year_text);
        holder.day_help = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.day_help);
        holder.month_help = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.month_help);

        holder.setTag(position);
        holder.setupInfoClickActions();
        holder.setupOnClickListener();
        holder.setTitle(ci.getTitle());
        holder.setSubtitle(ci.getSubtitle());
        holder.fixImageAndText(position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (CountdownViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.manageExpand(ci.getExpand(), ctx, position, mTitle.size());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the trace of the NullPointerException ?

Comment: please share your layout which you inflate in your adapter

Comment: Please share your adapter code as well

Comment: did you tried with lazy loading concept ?

Comment: @fiddler The logcat trace has been added

Comment: @talhakosen The layout has been added.

Comment: @VinaySShenoy The adapter code has been added.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys I don't see how that could be implemented in my situation. Please elaborate.

Comment: What is on line 104 of MainActivity.java ?

Comment: @fiddler It's listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(#6DCAEC")); That line of code doesn't cause my app to crash when I only have a few listitems.

Comment: where do you get the `position` from ?

Comment: @fiddler It's a parameter of onItemCheckedStateChanged which is a part of MultiChoiceModeListener.

Comment: Can you post the code for your MainActivity? The GC will not clear any resources as long as references to them exist, so that is not a problem.

Comment: @VinarySShenoy I actually figured it out, kinda. I didn't know getChildAt() was relativt to the listviews scroll progress so i rewrote some things and now that works.. I guess this whole thing with with on click effect is something else.